# Share Point Server 2010 issues

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to install SharePoint Server 2010 on my machine. I am already working on VS 2010 and VS 2012. They are installed on my machine and working perfectly.

I when i started to install Share Point Server 2010. The below highlighted links are not working

[image]

### **Nothing happens when i click these highlighted links.**

Can you tell if I am missing anything ?

Comment: You're missing some details.  What happens when you click these links?

Comment: nothing happens when i click these highlighted links.

Comment: Anything in the windows application log?

Comment: Where should i see the logs ?

Comment: your screenshot is a little different from what I remember, did you initiate the installation as outlined here... Step 3 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/ee554869(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is important to distinguish the type of installation and the **operating system** ( what version of windows ) your machine on which you intend to install; we assume here you decided for a  **Standalone** installation type (to install everything on one developer workstation).

With reference to the documentation: [Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/ee554869%28v=office.14%29.aspx), the following excerpt is relevant for your question:

> SharePoint requires your operating system to have certain
>   prerequisites installed before installation begins. For this reason,
>   SharePoint includes a PrerequisiteInstalle.exe tool that installs all
>   of these prerequisites for you. If your developer workstation is set
>   up with the Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 or Windows Server 2008
>   R2 operating system, you can install SharePoint 2010 by running the
>   PrerequisiteInstaller.exe tool (which is included with SharePoint
>   2010) to install the prerequisites that SharePoint needs, and then run
>   Setup.exe. However, you cannot use PrerequisiteInstaller.exe on
>   Windows 7 or Windows Vista.

For those operating systems, you must follow the additional instructions as descibed in chapter:**"Step 2: Install the Prerequisites for SharePoint 2010"** Of the [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/ee554869%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Unfortunately, in reading the doc some steps may seem confusing, therefore it may be helpful to follow more detailed instructions such as indicated in [installing sharepoint 2010 on windows 7 gotchas - blog.rafelo.com](http://blog.rafelo.com/2009/11/24/installing-sharepoint-2010-on-windows-7-gotchas/)

Especially about SharePoint.exe , that for many of us was nowhere to be found.

This **SharePoint.exe** file is actually the single executable contained within the ISO image of the  download… it could be for example: **en_office_sharepoint_server_2010_beta_x64_x16-19249.exe**. Depending on the build and version you downloaded, it could have a different name.

> Copy this file locally (do not run it), they suggest copying it to
>   C:\SharePointFiles Given the complex name I chose to rename it to
>   SharePoint.exe you may consider doing this as well as it makes the
>   following steps easier. The second sub-step instructs you to run a
>   command to extract the installation files. It shows you 2 sample
>   commands, one of which is: c:\SharePointFiles\SharePoint
>   /extract:c:\SharePointFiles
>
> Here simply replace SharePoint with the name of the executable, the
>   command should work just fine if you’ve renamed the executable to
>   SharePoint.exe
>
> Examples: c:\SharePointFiles\SharePoint.exe
>   /extract:c:\SharePointFiles or c:\SharePointFiles\OfficeServer.exe
>   /extract:c:\SharePointFiles or
>   c:\SharePointFiles\en_office_sharepoint_server_2010_beta_x64_x16-19249.exe
>   /extract:c:\SharePointFiles

Comment: Install Software PreRequisite and Install SharePoint Server, both links are doing nothing

Comment: Whan I am trying Step 2 **Extract the installation files by opening a Command Prompt window, and then typing the following command at the directory location of the folder where you copied the installation files in the previous step.** In Command Prompt, it is saying c:\sharepoint is not recognized as an internal or external command. In command prompt I typed **/extract:c:\SharePointFiles**

Comment: Open the SharePointServer.exe location from command prompt and run the following command. SharePointServer.exe /extract:C:\SharePointFiles
then continue Step 2 instruction. Just one question: what operating system run your machine?

Comment: This tutorial explain what we said before: http://blog.rafelo.com/2009/11/24/installing-sharepoint-2010-on-windows-7-gotchas/ also reading it could be usefull if it is appropriate for your environment

Comment: The error meaning is that you have not moved into the dir where you have copied your sharepointserver.exe file. Simply use the **cd** command change the current dir where the sharepointserver.exe is located. Also the blog I linked in the last comment explain very well this step.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38671/discussion-between-franco-rondini-and-abcdefghi)